# "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow() : ' function' and 'int' "

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am trying to solve **coupled ODEs**. It contains a function raised to power 2.

The following errors appears:

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow() : ' function' and 'int'  "
```

The function is:

```py
def psy_trial1(x,params,psy0=0):
    return x*(neural_neural(params,x)
def psy_trial2(x,params, psy0=0):
    return 1+x*neural_network(params,x)
def psy1(x, psy_trial1):
    return A(x)+B(x)*(psy_trial1)**2-psy_trial2
```

I think the problem is with function power. What is the right way to write a function having some integer power?

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide all the relevant information: what value does `x` gets when you run the code, how are `P` and `Q` defined and etc (basically, you should provide the relevant code to reproduce the error).

Comment: maybe you created function `def x()` and now `x**2` mead `function ** 2` and it is problem.

Comment: What are `psy_trial1` and `psy_trial2`? Your argument `psy_trail` might have a spelling error.

Comment: psy_trial1 and psy_trial2 are unknown functions

Comment: i have corrected spelling mistake

Comment: @Karim so you're trying to get power of function `psy_trial1`. If you want to get power of what this function returns, do `psy_trial1()` instead of `psy_trial1`

Comment: Could you define your function `psy1` with a generic parameter, like `def psy1(x,trial):`?

Comment: @Dr.lehmann x, params, psy0=0 are  parameters and variables

Comment: You are using a too suggestive parameter naming. The second parameter in `psy1` is a local variable for that function. Unfortunately you chose the same name as a function you previously defined. The local definition overwrites the previous one. So `psy_trial1` is the local parameter, `psy_trial2` the global function. To avoid such possibility of intuitive but wrong association, use a more generic name for the local variable, like just `trial`. If the function is correctly defined, it should be a simple search-and-replace, if not, then this parameter was perhaps unnecessary to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get power of function `psy_trial1` instead of value returned by that function, to fix that you have to call that function.
Another bug that I have found is that at the end of return statement in `psy1` function you are trying to subtract function `psy_trial2`. All fixes are here:

```
def psy_trial1(x,params,psy0=0):
    return x*(neural_neural(params,x)
def psy_trial2(x,params, psy0=0):
    return 1+x*neural_network(params,x)
def psy1(x, psy_trial1):
    return A(x)+B(x)*(psy_trial1())**2-psy_trial2()
```

Comment: This might get you the possible follow-up errors of *"too few arguments"* or *"calling a number as a function"*.